# Wordpress plugin for course registration

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a WordPress Page for course registration. All I want the plugin to do is send the filled in form details to my email ID and send an email to the user that he/she has successfully registered for the course. I don't need users to signup with username and password.

I've tried my luck with WP Forms but it only seems to have the option to forward the email to me and not the user.

Any suggestion on which plugin I should use?

Comment: Contact Form 7 is a very popular contact form plugin but requires some basic HTML knowledge. By default it won't store form submissions in the Wordpress database. You could also look at something like Gravity Forms which has a form builder for form creation, and easily editable confirmation messages for both the recipient and the sender.

Comment: I'll check those both. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hughes mentioned, you cant use wpcf7, and just hook on it to insert custom post on every query.

```
// Hook on wpcf7
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'do_on_cf7_submit', 50, 2 );
function do_on_cf7_submit($mail_params, $form = null) {
    // Empty post content
    $content = '';

    // set post content if field not empty
    if ($_POST['field-name'] != '') {
        $content .= 'Field Name Label: '.$_POST['field-name'] ;
    }


    // insert post if content not epmty
    if ($content != '')  {
        insertQueryPost($_POST['email'], $content);
    }  

    // allow cf7 to do his stuff
    return $mail_params;
}

// insert custom post type "query", don't forget to setup your custom post type first
function insertQueryPost($title, $content) {
    // insted of proper post slug, just make a hashed slug, when setting custom post type, set it to not public and not search-able
    $t = time();
    $thash = md5($t);

    $my_query = array(
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $title ),
        'post_content'  => $content,
        'post_type' => 'query',
        'post_name' => $thash,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1
    );
    $data = wp_insert_post( $my_query );
}
```